# CMake: Building a object file from a source in a object library in a sub directory out of source

Tags: cmake

Consider the following mock project with these files:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(myproject)
add_subdirectory(sub)
```

```
# sub/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(myLib OBJECT bar.c)
add_executable(foo foo.c)
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE myLib)
```

```
# sub/foo.c
int main() {return 0;}
```

```
# sub/bar.c
void bar(){}
```

When building in source after `cmake -G Unix\ Makefiles -B . -S .` I can go to the the directory sub and execute `make bar.o`. How can I achieve the same results when building out of source? I've tried these commands from the project root:

```
cmake -G Unix\ Makefiles -B test-build -S .
cmake --build test-build --target sub/bar.o
cmake --build test-build --target bar.o
cmake --build test-build --target bar
```

I get these kinds of error messages `gmake: *** No rule to make target 'sub/bar.o'.  Stop.`

I know it's possible to build the library, but in reality our library is quite large and I would like to focus on one file at the time.

Comment: `and execute make foo.o` then execute `--target foo.o`. Why the `sub/`?

Comment: I've tried `cmake --build test-build --target foo.o` aswell with similar results: `gmake: *** No rule to make target 'foo.o'.  Stop.`. I don't understand how to specify the target when it's in a sub directory.

Comment: Did you already tried `--target foo` ? AFAIK CMake generates a make target per CMake target plus some predefined targets as `all`, `test`, `clean`.

Comment: @vre Well, that worked in the mocked example given in the question. But it doesn't work when the file is added to an object library with `add_library(myLib OBJECT bar.c)`. I will update the question.

Comment: Then the CMake target would be `myLib`. But frankly, I don't know if CMake supports that for object libraries as they are a CMake concept and may not translate to the underlying build system.

Comment: @vre Thanks, this approach may be a dead end. I'll consider choosing another solution.

Comment: The actual object files are usually in internal folders, and last time I checked they have the pattern `${filename}.o` (so `bar.c.o`).  Your `make bar.o` likely isn't a cmake rule.

Comment: @StephenNewell When building in source `bar.o: bar.c.o` is in the file sub/Makefile, so it's generated by `cmake -G Unix\ Makefiles -B . ...` (It's even listed by `make help`, but bar.c.o is not.)